# PHP Processing stream_get_contents into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am having troubles converting a string which contains tab delimited CSV output 
into an array. While using the following code :

```
$data = stream_get_contents($request->getShipmentReport());
```

I get back data as following:

```
Date    Shipped     Comments        Feedback    Arrived on Time
5/11/15 2       comment         response    Yes
```

Now I would like to process this data into an array with the returned headers(line 1) as the index containing the value for each line which follows after that.

I am trying to end up with something like this :

```
$line['Date'] = 5/11/15
$line['Shipped'] = 2
$line['Feedback'] = response
$line['Arrived on Time']  yes
```

What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: you can use the function "fgetcsv" http://php.net/fgetcsv

Comment: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given ($data)

Comment: read the page i give you, there is a complete exemple of code

Comment: [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) is fgetcsv for strings.

Comment: the space between the data varies, so `str_getcsv` will return broken data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a library for handling CSV for example the [CSV-Package by The League of Extraordinary Packages](http://csv.thephpleague.com/)

You can pass your data and start working with array structures right away:

```
$csvString = stream_get_contents($request->getShipmentReport());
$csvReader = \League\Csv\Reader::createFromString($csvString);
$data = $csvReader->fetchAssoc(
    array('Date', 'Shipped', 'Comments', 'Feedback', 'Arrived on Time')
);
// Or since line 0 contains header
$data = $csvReader->fetchAssoc(0); // 0 is offset of dataset containing keys
```

Now your data should be in a structure like:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'Date' => '5/11/15',
        'Shipped' => '2',
        ...
    ),
    array(
        ...
    )
);
```

You can even filter out specific datasets and all kinds of fancy stuff. Just check the documentation I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

League CSV reader gives me a bad result. I use this instead:

```
          $csvReportString = stream_get_contents($request->getReport());
          $csvReportRows = explode("\n", $csvReportString);
          $report = [];
          foreach ($csvReportRows as $c) {
            var_dump($c);
            if ($c) { $report[] = str_getcsv($c, "\t");}
          }
          var_dump($report);
```